# Stripe Charges fails when using a Customer Source

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I'm trying to charge a customer with one of the stored credit cards. I'm passing the customer id in the request and I'm getting the customer info from Stripe just fine. The problem is when trying to make the charge to one of the customer sources the library returns an error `Must provide source or customer`. I checked the `sc.Sources.Data[1]` (its hardcoded here just for this example) and it has an actual cutsomer source. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: If I use a tok_1212321 token it works fine, but I don't find a way to retrieve the token id from stripe, only the cliente sources.

```golang
stripe.Key = os.Getenv("STRIPE_KEY")
sc, _ := stripeCustomer(request)

params := &stripe.ChargeParams{
    Amount:      stripe.Int64(int64(order.total * 100)),
    Currency:    stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
    Description: stripe.String("Order Number " + order.ID),
}

params.SetSource(sc.Sources.Data[1])

if _, err := charge.New(params); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I was missing is the `Customer` id. When doing a Charge both IDs have to be given.

```golang
params := &stripe.ChargeParams{
    Amount:      stripe.Int64(int64(order.total * 100)),
    Currency:    stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
    Description: stripe.String("Order Number " + order.ID),
    Customer:    stripe.String(sc.ID),
}

params.SetSource(sc.Sources.Data[1].ID)

if _, err := charge.New(params); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

This code makes it work.